# Purchase fails Flutter flutter_inapp_purchase

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I have a non-renewing subscription in iOS that fails during testing. I'm using the Flutter library flutter_inapp_purchase. I am getting the products to successfully load/fetch from iTunesConnect, but I get an error when attempting to purchase. This error occurs after I successfully enter my Sandbox user credentials.

I've tested this sandbox user and IAP setup using a previous version of the app built in Swift and everything works as expected, so I'm fairly certain the issue is something specific to this Flutter.

```
Purchase Started !!
2019-05-08 11:44:47.819382-0500 Runner[16255:3743382] 





 Purchase Failed  !!
2019-05-08 11:44:47.824961-0500 Runner[16255:3743449] flutter: Caused err. Set additionalSuccessPurchaseListenerIOS.
2019-05-08 11:44:47.825483-0500 Runner[16255:3743449] flutter: PlatformException(E_UNKNOWN, An unknown or unexpected error has occured. Please try again later., null)
2019-05-08 11:44:47.829865-0500 Runner[16255:3743449] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ios, platform not supported, null)
#0      FlutterInappPurchase.buyProduct (package:flutter_inapp_purchase/flutter_inapp_purchase.dart:269:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _PurchaseSubscriptionPageState.buyProduct (package:undaunted_golf_flutter/PurchaseSubscriptionPage.dart:98:58)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _PurchaseSubscriptionPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:undaunted_golf_flutter/PurchaseSubscriptionPage.dart:344:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
#4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:211:7)
#8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
#9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:225:20)
#10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22)
#11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
#12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
#13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
#14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
#15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
#17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
#18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
2019-05-08 11:45:22.597897-0500 Runner[16255:3743779] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x10ab13540] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-08 11:45:22.598180-0500 Runner[16255:3743779] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x10ab13540] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-08 11:45:22.598613-0500 Runner[16255:3743779] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
2019-05-08 11:45:22.598659-0500 Runner[16255:3743779] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

1) I decided to use the Package created by the Google Flutter team. https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

2) This spit out a more helpful error. I discovered that the issue was with the build number in my XCode runner project.

To fix: Document Outline - Runner
Make sure General Tab is selected
Targets - Runner
Replace Build number with a numerical value rather than $(FLUTTER....)

Comment: did you change back again to the other package? I'm looking into this right now and don't know which one should I use

Comment: @Dani Yes I did. After 3 days of struggling with this issue with the above package, switching to the package from the Flutter team allowed me to solve the problem almost right away.

Comment: do you know any good tutorial about subscriptions and upgrade? I only found this one but it's about consumable: https://youtu.be/NWbkKH-2xcQ

Comment: @Dani Here is the example from the Flutter team at Google: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/in_app_purchase/example/lib/main.dart